# Django: inspect queryset to get applied filters

Tags: django, django-queryset, introspection, inspection

Is there a way to inspect a queryset and get info about which filters/exclude have been applied?

I need it for debugging: I cannot understand why my queryset excludes some data...

Comment: You can use the `QuerySet.query` method to see what the SQL looks like, if you haven't already. Maybe that would help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That doesn't seem easy to do. Each filter is applied differently to the query object so you're not going to find a cleanly laid out `"filter1", "filter2", "filter3"`.

Check out `myqueryset.query.__dict__` - the incoming filter is separated into relevant areas immediately and no record stored. Details in `django.db.models.sql.query.Query`.

I'd check out the SQL instead.

```
print myqueryset.query
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use also:

```
your_qs.query.where.children
```

or:

```
your_qs._has_filters().__dict__['children']
```

and to access to the first filter that you applied:

```
your_qs._has_filters().__dict__['children'][0].__dict__
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are debugging in a shell:

```
from django.db import connection
print connection.queries
```

If you are making requests in a browser use django debug toolbar, it's a great tool and can be very helpful:

[Django Debug Toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar)